# What's new in Python 2.7.18?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So the [final Python 2 release](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/message/OFCIETIXLX34X7FVK5B5WPZH22HXV342/) is out. However, I can't find anywhere what has changed with this release. The corresponding [news](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Misc/NEWS.d/2.7.18.rst) page on GitHub is also empty. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Hmmmmm.... this does seem to be non-trivial information to find, I'm kind of surprised... +1 from me.

Comment: Umm the news page you linked says that: `There were no new changes in version 2.7.18.`

Comment: @rdas Then what's the point of the release? :)

Comment: You'd have to ask the python-devs that. I think it's just supposed to be a commemorative release like the mail mentions

Comment: It's possible there were no front-facing features added in 2.7.18, from the rc1 changelog it seems like only bugfixes & internal enhancements went in: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Misc/NEWS.d/2.7.18rc1.rst

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice question. You can find out for yourself by downloading and comparing the source code both for 2.7.17 and 2.7.18. Since 2.7 is my favorite flavor of Python I've decided to do it myself; here's a WinMerge screenshot:

[image]

Looks like there are some differences. On the other hand, `Misc\NEWS` clearly states:

> ## What's New in Python 2.7.18 final?
>
> *Release date: 2020-04-19*
>
> There were no new changes in version 2.7.18.

That, IMHO, is not *completely* true but before getting into it let's first see what most of those differences are about. Again, the changes are listed inside `Misc\NEWS` and they relate to version 2.7.18rc1:

> ## What's New in Python 2.7.18 release candidate 1?
>
> *Release date: 2020-04-04*
>
> ### Security
>
> - bpo-38945: Newline characters have been escaped when performing uu   encoding to prevent them from overflowing into to content section of
>   the   encoded file. This prevents malicious or accidental modification
>   of data   during the decoding process.
> - bpo-38804: Fixes a ReDoS vulnerability in :mod:`http.cookiejar`. Patch by   Ben Caller.
>
> ### Core and Builtins
>
> - bpo-38535: Fixed line numbers and column offsets for AST nodes for calls   without arguments in decorators.
>
> ### Library
>
> - bpo-38576: Disallow control characters in hostnames in http.client,   addressing CVE-2019-18348. Such potentially malicious header injection
>   URLs now cause a InvalidURL to be raised.
> - bpo-27973: Fix urllib.urlretrieve failing on subsequent ftp transfers from   the same host.
>
> ### Build
>
> - bpo-38730: Fix problems identified by GCC's `-Wstringop-truncation`   warning.
>
> ### Windows
>
> - bpo-37025: `AddRefActCtx()` was needlessly being checked for failure in   `PC/dl_nt.c`.
>
> ### macOS
>
> - bpo-38295: Prevent failure of test_relative_path in test_py_compile on   macOS Catalina.
>
> ### C API
>
> - bpo-38540: Fixed possible leak in :c:func:`PyArg_Parse` and similar   functions for format units `"es#"` and `"et#"` when the macro
>   :c:macro:`PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN` is not defined.

So, it looks like 2.7.18 is just a wrap-around of 2.7.18rc1 but is that all? To be exact, there are a few changes that belong to 2.7.18 and have to do with **marking** it as the final release of Python 2 and warn the user about the EOL of the product. For example, in `tools\templates\layout.html` you can find the block below:

> {% block header %} {%- if outdated %} 
> {% trans %}This document is for an old version of Python that is {% endtrans %}[{%
> trans %}no longer supported{% endtrans %}](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/#end-of-life-branches).
> {% trans %}You should upgrade and read the {% endtrans %}
> [{% trans
> %} Python documentation for the current stable release{% endtrans
> %}](https://docs.python.org/%7B%7B%20language%20+%20%27/%27%20if%20language%20and%20language%20!=%20%27en%27%20else%20%27%27%20%7D%7D3/%7B%7B%20pagename%20%7D%7D%7B%7B%20file_suffix%20%7D%7D).  {%- endif %} {% endblock %}

So, I believe, the **reasoning** behind that final version is twofold: (a) finalize the changes of 2.7.18rc1 and (b) mark it as the final release of Python 2 and let the user know about it.